# ColdFusion 10 REST API: How to get cfthrow to return JSON with Camel Case properties

Tags: api, rest, exception, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10's new REST API.  Let's say I throw this exception:

```
<cfthrow errorcode="400" message="Validation error." type="ValidationException" />
```

ColdFusion handles exceptions well and returns this JSON in the response body:

```
{"Message":"Validation error.","Type":"ValidationException"}
```

Notice that the properties 'Message' and 'Type' are generated in Pascal Case (upper case first letter).  For this to be consistent with everything else in my API, I need the properties to be Came Case (lower case first letter), such as the following:

```
{"message":"Validation error.","type":"ValidationException"}
```

Any idea how I can do this?  I'm looking for a way to tweak the way ColdFusion generates the JSON without manually doing a cfcatch and generating the JSON myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<cfcatch>` it and return your own custom JSON string constructed from the exception's message and details.

I don't think you can tweak it unless you have the source from Adobe. :)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.  The more I get familiar with CF 10's REST API, the more I end up overriding the built-in features.

Comment: I haven't played with REST in CF10 (we're still using CF9), but I've heard many complains lately.  Maybe it's time to just go straight to Scala Play next.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IIS with ColdFusion, here's a way to solve this problem without resorting to using `<cfcatch>` and rolling your own response on every API endpoint (which is a real pain).

I wrote an HttpModule in .NET that taps into IIS' response pipeline to modify the response returned by ColdFusion.  It only interferes if the response Content-Type is `application/json` and the status code doesn't not start with a `2` (i.e. it's not a successful response). All of the code is available here:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process

Here is how to use the HttpModule.

**1) Grab the DLL**

Grab the `ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.dll` file from here and drop it into the bin folder of your ColdFusion application:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process/tree/master/bin/Release

For example, if your ColdFusion application is here:

```
C:/myapp
```

Then you want to put the dll here:

```
C:/myapp/bin/ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.dll
```

If you don't want to trust a stranger's DLL, you'll need to review the source code and compile the project in Visual Studio yourself to generate the DLL.

**2) Modify web.config**

Modify or create the web.config file in the root of your application. The content should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <!-- This is for IIS5, IIS6, and IIS7 Classic -->
            <add name="JsonCamelCasePropertyConverterModule" type="ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.JsonCamelCasePropertyConverterModule"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <!-- This is for IIS7+ Integrated mode -->
            <add name="JsonCamelCasePropertyConverterModule" type="ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.JsonCamelCasePropertyConverterModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

That's it. Your error response will now look like this:

```
{"message":"Email is invalid.","type":"ValidationException"}
```

If you want to know how I created this HttpModule, the source code is available here:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process/blob/master/JsonCamelCasePropertyConverterModule.cs

and here:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process/blob/master/UTF8SanitizerStream.cs

Comment: Ditto.. and great instructions. +1